# How to create a custom CLI warning

Tags: command-line, terminal

In Terminal, how can set up a custom warning so that when I type a specific command like

```
git pull origin master
```

the command doesn't go through and I get a warning output like

```
Did you mean git rebase origin/master?
```

I've considered creating a bash script or simply using an alias in my bash profile but I'm not sure what the best method would be.

Thanks.

Comment: Should the solution be flexible enough to catch, for instance, `git pull -v origin master`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not any hooks for `pre-pull` but you might find this useful https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_merge

Hooks in general are nice, if you did not know about them.

---

As for alias you would have to create one for `git`, as in create a function in `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases` and check if arguments are pull origin master, if not invoke git, else print warning. Or an alias named git to a custom script - in effect a wrapper script for git.

In short because an alias can not contain spaces, hence the alias would have to be for the first *"word"* aka command.

In `.bash_aliases` or the like:

```bsh
mygit()
{
    if [ "$1" = "pull" ] && \
        [ "$2" = "origin" ] && \
        [ "$3" = "master" ]; then
        printf 'Did you mean git rebase origin/master?\n' >&2
        return 1
    else
        git "$@"
    fi
}

alias git=mygit
```

Or name function `git` but call git internally by:

```
command git "$@"
```

in stead of `git "@$"`.

Also note:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases

> For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases.